# Group categories in R according to first letters of a string?

Tags: r, text, dataset, grouping

I have a dataset loaded in R, and I have one of the columns that has text. This text is not unique (any row can have the same value) but it represents a specific condition of a row, and so the first 3-5 letters of this field will represent the group where the row belongs. Let me explain with an example.

Having 3 different rows, only showing the id and the column I need to group by:

```
ID........... TEXTFIELD    
1............ VGH2130    
2............ BFGF2345    
3............ VGH3321
```

Having the previous example, I would like to create a new column in the dataframe where it would be set the group such as

```
ID........... TEXTFIELD........... NEWCOL    
1............ VGH2130............. VGH    
2............ BFGF2345............ BFGF    
3............ VGH3321............. VGH
```

And to determine the groups that would be formed in this new column, I would like to make an array with the possible groups to make (since all the rows will be contained in one of these groups) (for example `c <- ("VGH","BFGF",......)` )

Can anyone drop any light on how to efficiently do this? (without making a for loop having to do this, since I have millions of rows and this would take ages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also try

```
> data$group <- (str_extract(TEXTFIELD, "[aA-zZ]+"))
> data
  ID TEXTFIELD group
1  1   VGH2130   VGH
2  2  BFGF2345  BFGF
3  3   VGH3321   VGH
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try, if `df` is your data.frame:

```
df$NEWCOL <- gsub("([A-Z)]+)\\d+.*","\\1", df$TEXTFIELD)

> df
#  ID TEXTFIELD NEWCOL
#1  1   VGH2130    VGH
#2  2  BFGF2345   BFGF
#3  3   VGH3321    VGH
```

Comment: Is there also a way to exclude certain strings from being modified by `gsub` if predefined in a list?

Comment: @Martin very likely but could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

Does the text field always have 3 or 4 letters preceding the numbers?

you can check that by doing:

```
nrow(data[grepl("[aA-zZ]{1,4}\\d+", data$TEXTFIELD)== TRUE, ]) #this gives number of rows where TEXTFIELD contains 3,4 letters followed by digits
```

If yes, then:

```
require(stringr)
data$NEWCOL <- str_extract(data$TEXTFIELD, "[aA-zZ]{1,4}")
```

Final Step:

```
data$group <- ifelse(data$NEWCOL == "VGH", "Group Name", ifelse(data$NEWCOL == "BFGF", "Group Name", ifelse . . . . ))
```

`# Complete the ifelse statement to classify all groups`